# Java add object to list

Tags: java, list, object

Im currently using the following code

Panel class

```
static List<Shoots> bullets;

public Panel() {

    bullets = new ArrayList<>();

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
}
```

Another class

```
Panel.bullets.add(new Shoots(1, Panel.headx, Panel.heady));

class Shoots {

    private int speed;

    private int x;

    private int y;

    public Shoots(int speed, int x, int y) {

        this.speed = speed;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        getX();

    }

    public int getX() {

        return this.x;
    }
}
```

Then when I try to System.out.println(Panel.bullets); I get

[]

How can I do this the proper way?

Comment: Have you tried to read some kind of tutorial for Java ?

Comment: The fact that you're declaring bullets statically, but allocating it in the instance constructor, does not look right. In what order are you creating and adding the items and printing out the list?

Comment: Why are you instantiating the static List in the object constructor?

Comment: Panel class constructor is initializing the static member bullets. So any where in the code if you instantiate Panel class, bullets get reset. Read about singleton pattern if you want static member

Answer (score 0):

`bullets` arraylist is empty i.e. zero elements. Thats why you are getting that output.
Also, your list is static and you are asssigning the values everytime in the constructor. That will create a new arraylist and assign it to `bullets` variable everytime an object is created. Also, you aren't adding anything into the list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add anything into bullet list before using? Every time you initialize it inside constructor. so Every new object of `Panel` class will initialize it and do empty. so create and initialize at class level.  i.e.

```
static List<Shoots> bullets= new ArrayList<>();
```